# 'mat-expansion-panel' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-modules

I'm currently using this Angular module Material Expansion Panel, it's working fine on local but when I try to build it in prod, it throws me this error :

```
    'mat-expansion-panel' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-expansion-panel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-expansion-panel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I don't really know what to do to ignore this message, since I already have 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' in my AppModule.

Here's my code with this expansion panel :

```
            <mat-accordion class="card">
            <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
              <mat-expansion-panel-header class="card-header">
                <i class="fa fa-thermometer-three-quarters fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-top:5px;  color: Tomato;"></i> 
                <mat-panel-title> 
                 <b> How to choose the criticality level</b>
                </mat-panel-title>
                <mat-panel-description>
                  Summary table
                </mat-panel-description>
              </mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <p><img src="../../../../assets/level.png" width="900px"></p>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
```

My package.json (I can't update the packages for compatibility reasons) :

```
    {
  "name": "HomeFront",
  "version": "1.1.2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod&& node versionManagement.js",
    "build:local": "ng build --prod",
    "test:w": "ng test --watch --browsers=Chrome --source-map=false",
    "test": "ng test --source-map=false --code-coverage --source-map=false",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compodoc": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "2.0.0",
    "angular-material-expansion-panel": "^0.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.6.12",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.2.0",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Parts of my AppModule.ts :

```
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule, JsonpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';


import {AppComponent} from './app.component';


@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ],
    imports: [
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        JsonpModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true})
    ],
    providers: [
        xxxx
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve? I'm having the same issue with 'mat-accordion'...

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right. Did you **stop** & **restart** your development server of **Angular**? Also adding **modules** (or doing `-npm install`) while `ng serve` is active does not correctly update the project.